# Thickness of Pi 7" Display + driver?

Tags: display

I'd like to know the approximate **thickness** (as in, z-axis) measurement from the very front of the Raspberry Pi 7" display, *with the display driver mounted*, to the furthest back piece of said driver, *excluding the Pi*; I'll mount the actual Pi (4B) separately, extending the power cables and FFC. I couldn't find dimensions of this anywhere; only of the screen itself.

PS - Or, if anyone has yet found a way to extend the (orange) ribbon cables and mount the driver board separately altogether, that'd be amazing. (said cables would have to be able to last being constantly flexed though, as it's part of a laptop)

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this helps as a worse case (sorry) size to go with https://smarticase.com/pages/cad-downloads as this also includes space for the Pi on the back of the screen.

Comment: display `depth` is the number of bits per pixel, not the size of the display ... physical size parameters are `height` and `width`

Comment: @Andyroo that actually helps a lot, the second image shows that it's under 3.5cm. I'm not sure if that includes the Pi or not though.

Comment: @jsotola "Depth" was the only word that I could think of at the time; I already know the height and width. I'll make sure to clarify tin the post that I'm not referring to display depth.

Comment: I think that does include the Pi as the case is designed to enclose it and have the fan cooling the Pi. Pic 9 on https://smarticase.com/collections/all/products/smartipi-touch-2 shows Pi fitted below the fan

Comment: @Galaxy I understand now ... the term is `thickness`  ... think of pizza

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/display/7InchDisplayDrawing-14092015.pdf

Comment: @Dougie sorry, unless I'm missing it, this doesn't provide the thickness with the display driver installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The front of the viewing surface to the back of the display controller PCB is 9.8mm.
- The Raspberry (3B+) on top of that is 14.75 mm (it's mounted on 10mm stand-offs)
- The TV HAT on the Raspberry is 13.5 mm (it's also mounted on 8mm standoffs)

That's on a bare system without a case.

So total depth is 38mm (not allowing for any header pins and based on my Raspberry having a TV HAT as my display is my portable DVB-T telly).